# Expandable LIst with Drag and Drop feature in android

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop, expandablelistview

i want to create a Expandable listview with drag and drop feature i.e i can arrange inner or outer item through Drag and Drop

Comment: can you plz post the solution if you have implemented it. it will be helpful to others as well.

Comment: hey did you get the solution? I am still in it

Answer (score 1):

You create a drag event listener object ("listeners") from a class that implements View.OnDragListener.You set the drag event listener object for a View with the View object's setOnDragListener() method. Each View object also has a onDragEvent() callback method. Both of these are described in more detail in the  [developer section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) .

Refer this link for working sample :
 [`bit.ly/16r49T3`](http://bit.ly/16r49T3)

Comment: Hello Rizvan i didnt get your link may you plaese send again thank you

Comment: @RadimKöhler Yes i did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a few listeners to get this to work.  These listeners I placed in the OnStart of the fragment they appear in.

First Listener is as follows, assuming you called your listview "lvListView" (this was for dragging the child around, I found it elsewhere on here):

```
    lvListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
                int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);

                // You now have everything that you would as if this was an OnChildClickListener()
                // Add your logic here.

                //include this:
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, lvItems.getItemAtPosition(position), 0);
                // Return true as we are handling the event.
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

That allows you to drag the child around, but now you need a listener for all your DubSteppin' (the Drop).  I placed the following just after that in my code:

```
     lvListView.setOnDragListener(new AdapterView.OnDragListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    //layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                    Log.i("msg", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");

                    // Do nothing
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    Log.i("msg", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                    int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    Log.i("msg", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    Log.i("msg", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    Log.i("msg", Integer.toString(x_cord) + "," + Integer.toString(y_cord));
                    int nPointToPosition = lvListView.pointToPosition(x_cord,y_cord);
                    if(lvListView.getItemAtPosition(nCheck)!= null) {

                        // THE FUN PART IS HERE!
                        // ******this is the header list number******
                        int ngroupPosition = lvListView.getPackedPositionGroup(lvListView.getExpandableListPosition(nCheck));

                        // ******this is the child position******
                        int nchildPosition = lvListView.getPackedPositionChild(lvListView.getExpandableListPosition(nCheck));

                    }
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    Log.i("msg", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
                    // This is where I added some activities....
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Log.i("msg", "ACTION_DROP event");
                    // This is also a good place, place with it and see what you want to do
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            //return value
            return true;
        }
    });//end DragListener
```

Sorry to "necropost", but I wanted to pay it forward, since usually I find my answers in code blocks like this on here.

I also got most of this from other code blocks and figured my way through it, so if you recognize your code, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to these two links :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/tlv/TouchListView.java

Comment: The second link's response is 404.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for a solution, I modified the drag and drop listview and updated it to drag and drop expandable listview, check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895770/how-to-implement-expandablelistview-with-drag-and-drop-list-items-in-android/19331890#19331890)